# Java: How to use grammars to write a translator

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am trying to write a translator that converts infix to prefix. I know the grammars and read the "Compilers Principles, Techniques, & Tools" and searched a lot but since I'm new to java(and programming in general) and all the web is filled with the stack method I don't even know where to start.

I'm not asking for the whole code I just need an example, a link or anything to understand how should I do it (without using Arrays, Dynamic Arrays, [Stack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-infix-prefix-notation/) and anything that is taught in a data structure).

In the book, they use this way to convert infix to postfix

```java
import java.io.*;
class Parser {
    static int lookahead;
    
    public Parser() throws IOException {
        lookahead = System.in.read();
    }
    
    void expr() throws IOException {
        term();
        while(true) {
            if (lookahead == '+'){
                match('+'); term(); System.out.write('+');
                
            }
            else if ( lookahead == '-') {
                match('-'); term(); System.out.write('-');
            
                
            }
            else return;
        }
    }
    void term() throws IOException {
        if ( Character.isDigit((char)lookahead )) {
            System.out.write((char)lookahead); match(lookahead);
        }
        else throw new Error("Syntax Error");
    }
    
    void match(int t) throws IOException {
        if(lookahead == t) lookahead = System.in.read();
        else throw new Error("Syntax Error");
    }    
}

 class Postfix {
    public static void main(String[] arges) throws IOException{
        Parser parse = new Parser();
        parse.expr(); System.out.write('\n');
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you match '+' and '-' and then print to the screen, you need to build a [parse tree.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree) instead of printing.  Then you walk the tree to produce the infix.

Comment: Are you simply asking how to convert that class to generate prefix instead of postfix?  If yes, the "way to start" is to read that code and understand what it does and how it does it.  Converting it to generate prefix is almost trivial ... once you understand it.

Comment: But note that what you are actually asking is totally different to the title of your question.  You should EDIT the question to fix the title and make other changes to make it clearer what you are actually asking.

Comment: Also, "show me how to do something which requires a stack without confusing me by talking about stacks" is really not a good question. It's like asking how to cook an omelette without referring to cooking utensils like frying pans.

Answer (score -1):

You can look at this package:

[The Compiler Generator Coco/R](https://ssw.jku.at/Research/Projects/Coco/)

They have a version for Java.